# what is the best way to test DLL functions ?

Tags: c++, c, testing, dll, lua

I want to test my function and flows.
Lua scripts are a way for testing, Im able to load C Lib from lua and invoke the functions. The greatest advantage of using Lua is if you want to change calling scenerio, you just have to change your lua script file and execute it.

But I want to know that are there any better way to test a DLL code?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing exist in the universe as "the best way".<sup>Citation needed</sup>

However, the generally accepted practice currently is to write [automated unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). That is, you use [a unit testing framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) that allows you to express different scenarios of the consumption of the library code. You may think of tests as of a huge bunch of little programs that use the functions and classes in the library to verify their correctness, except that you don't actually write main functions, makefiles, printing and all the boring stuff is handled for you. Tests can pass or fail individually. Usually you can give names to them and organize into blocks. When test fails, a framework typically explain where and why, reducing the time and effort required for the debugging.

Unit tests are frequently [built and ran automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation), e.g. by the IDE or a watch script after rebuilding your library and/or by a [continuous integration system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) after a commit into a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Generally you write tests in the same language as your library (it's just simpler), but if your library is designed to interface with other languages you can of course use any or multiple of these languages as well.

There is an entire branch of programming methodology that is based on unit testing, called [Test-driven development (TDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). In short, TDD instructs you to write a unit test first for a given scenario and only then the simplest library code that allows the test to pass.

Few examples of unit testing frameworks for C++ (no particular order):

- [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest)
- [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html)
- [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)
- [Catch](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2)